# ApiPlatform + JwtAuthenticationBundle

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am trying to configure api platform with JwtAuthenticationBundle, on top of a Symfony 4 app, without FOSUserBundle.

I want to be able to use the swagger interface.

```
# config/packages/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    swagger:
        api_keys:
            - { name: 'Authorization', type: 'header' }
    mapping:
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
```

and my security file:

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        db_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: db_provider
            form_login:
                check_path: /api/login_check
                username_parameter: _username
                password_parameter: _password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        main:
            pattern:   ^/api
            provider: db_provider
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            lexik_jwt: ~

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

If I follow the [doc](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/jwt/#installing-lexikjwtauthenticationbundle), I am not able to see my swagger page, I have a 401 - Bad credentials on /api. I am so not able to login through the "Authorize" button on swagger UI.
I have to replace, in the access control part: `- { path: ^/, roles: [ ROLE_READER ] }` by `- { path: ^/, roles: [ IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY ] }` to do so.

I don't know if I missunderstand/missconfigure something, or if there is a mistake in the documentation

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I had found is to modify the access_control, by adding a slash to the second path:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```